# Which method is more convenient for designing pdf data entry form?

Tags: adobe, designer, itext

I would require to design data entry form in pdf which will be filled by user and they will save and send back to me via an e-mail.Which method should I go with ? I was looking into iText documentation and it looks pretty tough to design complex data entry interface. How about adobe LiveCycle ?

Rishi

Comment: I got the answer, posted with details on my blog ([http://planetlotus.org/73cdb4](http://planetlotus.org/73cdb4))